# Item Decoration adds double space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have a recycler view where I want to add a space between the cells.
Using the code below works however, In the middle The space is doubled.

How can I space them and avoid the double space at the middle?

```
public class ItemDecorationAlbumColumns extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public ItemDecorationAlbumColumns(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;

        // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
        if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.top = space;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorationAlbumColumns(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the code below:

```
public class ItemDecorationAlbumColumns extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public ItemDecorationAlbumColumns(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) % 2 == 0) {
            outRect.right = space;
            outRect.bottom = space;
            outRect.left = space/2;
        } else {
            outRect.left = space;
            outRect.right = space/2;
            outRect.bottom = space;
        }

        if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.top = space;
            outRect.left = space;
        }
    }
}
```